# Can't click a button due to a sticky button presence

Tags: java, android, appium, ui-automation

Due to presence of a sticky chat button, I can not click a button on screen on my Appium test. Can anyone help?

Code

```
public static void TapViewBookingButton() throws InterruptedException 
{
    Setup.startTimer();
    MobileElement btnViewBooking = (MobileElement) Setup.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(btnViewBooking_ID)));
    btnViewBooking.click();
    Setup.updateLogMessage("VIEW BOOKING button clicked in " + Setup.stopTimer(Setup.stopWatch), SM_CONSTANTS.isScreenshot);
}
```

buttonViewBooking.Click() - (VIEW BOOKING) doesn't work as shown in the picture due to a sticky online chat sticky button shown on the bottom right of the screen

[image]

Logs:

> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/7ee1afc3-9a7c-4105-b8e9-acdbf9570f46/elements {"using":"id","value":"com.servicemarket.app.debug:id/btnViewBooking"}
>   info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.servicemarket.app.debug:id/btnViewBooking","context":"","multiple":true}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.servicemarket.app.debug:id/btnViewBooking","context":"","multiple":true}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.servicemarket.app.debug:id/btnViewBooking using ID with the contextId:  multiple: true
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.servicemarket.app.debug:id/btnViewBooking]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.servicemarket.app.debug:id/btnViewBooking]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.servicemarket.app.debug:id/btnViewBooking]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (1)
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=1, RESOURCE_ID=com.servicemarket.app.debug:id/btnViewBooking]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":[{"ELEMENT":"126"}],"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"126"}],"sessionId":"7ee1afc3-9a7c-4105-b8e9-acdbf9570f46"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/7ee1afc3-9a7c-4105-b8e9-acdbf9570f46/elements 200 36.010 ms - 91 {"status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"126"}],"sessionId":"7ee1afc3-9a7c-4105-b8e9-acdbf9570f46"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/7ee1afc3-9a7c-4105-b8e9-acdbf9570f46/element/126/click {"id":"126"}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"126"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"126"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"7ee1afc3-9a7c-4105-b8e9-acdbf9570f46"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/7ee1afc3-9a7c-4105-b8e9-acdbf9570f46/element/126/click 200 306.260 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"7ee1afc3-9a7c-4105-b8e9-acdbf9570f46"}

Comment: Please provide more information. A screenshot, an output of the DOM, the code you're attempting to use.

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 1):

So you can get element. Thats already good. Try to click with `TouchAction`, e.g. `press` or `longPress`:

```
Point point = btnViewBooking.getLocation();
new TouchAction(driver)
    .longPress(point.getX(), point.getY())
    .release()
    .perform();
```

Comment: Are you able to use Appium Inspector (part of Appium Desktop - https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop). You can record a click action in there. It'll likely use xpath, but that may give you a clue about a visibility or layering issue.